# Arrange the chart's x-axis

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I try to place each text in its respective place, but the text comes out with a jump in position, thus exemplifying that there are 15 sets of bars in the graph, but only 8 have their nomenclature on the x-axis.

Each set of bars has its own name.

```
andar = ['0', '23º andar',  '22º andar',    '21º andar',    '20º andar',    '19º andar',    '18º andar',    '17º andar',
       '16º andar', '15º andar',    '14º andar',    '13º andar',    '12º andar',    '11º andar',    'Térreo A', 'Térreo B']
ano_1=[285, 107, 38,    61, 62, 93, 45, 68, 88, 60, 77, 61, 60, 457,    34,]
ano_2=[336, 38, 24, 72, 64, 92, 52, 72, 94, 63, 80, 41, 65, 431,    45]
ano_3=[277, 12, 21, 19, 38, 86, 37, 45, 68, 55, 61, 15, 43, 431,    27]
ano_4=[261, 8,  2,  4,  46, 91, 33, 41, 61, 55, 55, 22, 41, 452,    21]
ano_5=[222, 2,  2,  6,  46, 80, 33, 41, 63, 61, 57, 26, 39, 457,    14]

barWidth = 0.14  # the width of the bars

fig, ax = plt.subplots(constrained_layout=True, figsize=(30, 12))
rects1 = np.arange(len(ano_1))
rects2 = [x + barWidth for x in rects1]
rects3 = [x + barWidth for x in rects2]
rects4 = [x + barWidth for x in rects3]
rects5 = [x + barWidth for x in rects4]

plt.bar(rects1, ano_1, width=barWidth, label = 2018)
plt.bar(rects2, ano_2, width=barWidth, label = 2019)
plt.bar(rects3, ano_3, width=barWidth, label = 2020)
plt.bar(rects4, ano_4, width=barWidth, label = 2021)
plt.bar(rects5, ano_5, width=barWidth, label = 2022)


# Add some text for labels, title and custom x-axis tick labels, etc.
ax.set_ylabel('Consumo')
ax.set_title('Consumo de energia por andar')
ax.set_xticklabels(labels = andar, rotation = 45)
ax.legend()


fig.tight_layout()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Remove `'0'` in `andar` and add `ax.set_xticks(np.arange(len(andar)))`.

[image]

#### Code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

andar = ['23º andar', '22º andar', '21º andar', '20º andar', '19º andar', '18º andar', '17º andar',
         '16º andar', '15º andar', '14º andar', '13º andar', '12º andar', '11º andar', 'Térreo A', 'Térreo B']
ano_1 = [285, 107, 38, 61, 62, 93, 45, 68, 88, 60, 77, 61, 60, 457, 34, ]
ano_2 = [336, 38, 24, 72, 64, 92, 52, 72, 94, 63, 80, 41, 65, 431, 45]
ano_3 = [277, 12, 21, 19, 38, 86, 37, 45, 68, 55, 61, 15, 43, 431, 27]
ano_4 = [261, 8, 2, 4, 46, 91, 33, 41, 61, 55, 55, 22, 41, 452, 21]
ano_5 = [222, 2, 2, 6, 46, 80, 33, 41, 63, 61, 57, 26, 39, 457, 14]

barWidth = 0.14  # the width of the bars

fig, ax = plt.subplots(constrained_layout=True, figsize=(30, 12))
rects1 = np.arange(len(ano_1))
rects2 = [x + barWidth for x in rects1]
rects3 = [x + barWidth for x in rects2]
rects4 = [x + barWidth for x in rects3]
rects5 = [x + barWidth for x in rects4]

plt.bar(rects1, ano_1, width=barWidth, label=2018)
plt.bar(rects2, ano_2, width=barWidth, label=2019)
plt.bar(rects3, ano_3, width=barWidth, label=2020)
plt.bar(rects4, ano_4, width=barWidth, label=2021)
plt.bar(rects5, ano_5, width=barWidth, label=2022)

# Add some text for labels, title and custom x-axis tick labels, etc.
ax.set_ylabel('Consumo')
ax.set_title('Consumo de energia por andar')

ax.set_xticks(np.arange(len(andar)))
ax.set_xticklabels(labels=andar, rotation=45)

ax.legend()

plt.show()
```